# RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_SPEECH_INPUT_COMPLETE_SILENCE_LENGTH_MILLIS not working

Tags: android, speech-recognition

Ok, I know this has been an issue tracked since the release of Jelly Bean.  I would like to extend the time before the speech.recognizer shuts off.  I'm aware that the documentation states "Additionally, depending on the recognizer implementation, these values may have no effect."

So, If I want this to work is there a solution to "implementing" the recognizer or is this simply a limit prescribed by Google and we have no way to implement the recognizer so these values do mean something?

```
  Intent i = new Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH);
            i.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_SPEECH_INPUT_MINIMUM_LENGTH_MILLIS, Long.valueOf(10000));
            i.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_SPEECH_INPUT_COMPLETE_SILENCE_LENGTH_MILLIS, Long.valueOf(10000));
            i.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_SPEECH_INPUT_POSSIBLY_COMPLETE_SILENCE_LENGTH_MILLIS, Long.valueOf(10000));
            i.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_MODEL, "en-US");
```

If Google has set the parameters, does anyone have a workaround?

Comment: I'm afraid Google still doesn't support these values and to make things worse, in the latest Google Now release, the amount of 'silence' allowed before the user speaks was greatly reduced. I have reported this.